# Gradient Border Using GIMP

Tags: gimp, gradient

I am starting with a blank canvas in GIMP.  I want to create a gradient border around the entire perimeter of the image.  I am not looking for fade to transparency or feathering the edges (which there are many tutorials for).

I want to create a Gradient using the gradient tool that goes from foreground color to background color.  Unfortunately the gradient tool only allows you to do 1 of the 4 edges.  How can I do this using the gradient tool?

Here is the bad part.  I've done this before and can't remember how I did it.  I attached a picture so you can see what I'm trying to do.  I need to do it again because I want to change the color.

[image]

Comment: There is a "square" shape setting in the Gradient tool options in GIMP, but it would need to be applied to a square and not a rectangle. But your example doesn't look like it was created that way. [See example here](https://imgur.com/XA71Bu6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have 2 empty layers, both full sized and with alpha channel or at least the top layer must have alpha channel

Fill the bottom layer with the background color.

Make a rectangular selection, smaller than the layer and fill it with the foreground color in the top layer:

[image]

Blur the top layer:

[image]

Keep the layers separate as long as you are not sure if some adjustments are needed.

Comment: Thanks.  That works.  I thought I did it the first time with the gradient tool, but this works just as well.

Comment: Only problem is I'm  not getting to blur like you are.  "Make a rectangular selection, smaller than the layer and fill it with the foreground color:" Is this on the top or bottom later?

Comment: The yellowish rectangle is in the top layer. Both layers must be as big. This doesn't work if the top layer hasn't room for the blur.

Answer (score 3):

Another method:

1. Set foreground/backgroud to the two colors
2. `Select>All`
3. Start the Blend tool, with

   - gradient: `FG to BG (RGB)`
   - shape: `Shaped (Spherical)`
4. Click and drag on the image, this will create a shaped gradient, as well as adding a control line.
5. Click on the middle of the line to add a control point, and slide it to adjust the color transition. You can also change the blend characteristic (used `Spherical(decreasing)`)

[image]

6. Strike [enter] or double-click when happy with the result
7. You can apply a bit of Gaussian blur to the result:

[image]

Comment: This answer actually does what the question asks instead of providing a workaround and this also works with arbitrary selection shapes! Saved my day. :^)